# Nested for loop issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, python-3.x

I am having trouble wrapping my head around this for loop. I can't seem to get it to work properly.

What I am trying to do is have it build a string of title then info, title then info, etc.

This is my loop:

```
for pod in root.findall('.//pod'):
        title = pod.attrib['title'] + "\n\n"
        joined += title
        for pt in root.findall('.//plaintext'):
            if pt.text:
                info = " " + pt.text + "\n\n"
                joined += info
```

This may be a stupid question but any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your *input* (`root`), *output*, and *expected output*?

Comment: Also I see you've tagged this post with python-2.7 *and* python-3.x. I assume you're only using one.

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
Try buffering all data and then obtain the string you want.
I'm assuming your want output like

title1 info1
title1 info1
title1 info2
title1 info2
title2 info1
title2 info2
...
...

"""


import StringIO

my_string_buf = StringIO.StringIO()
for pod in root.findall('.//pod'):
    for pt in root.findall('.//plaintext'):
         if pt.text:
              my_string_buf.write("{0} {1}\n".format(pod, pt.text))

# Reset buffer.
my_string_buf.seek(0)

# Obtain the string.
my_string = my_string_buf.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

By nesting the loops you're basically setting up a graph with the first loop's values on the x axis and the second loop's values on the y axis. This will get you output with all possible values mixed together. For example, if your titles are: ["Holy Grail", "Life of Brian", "Flying Circus"] and your info is ["Overwatched", "NSFW", "Perfectly Absurd"] your output would be:

```
"""
Holy Grail Overwatched
Holy Grail NSFW
Holy Grail Perfectly Absurd
Life of Brian Overwatched
...
"""
```

To solve this issue you need to find some way to associate the title and the info. For example, you might be able to merge the `root.findall()` calls to grab both pieces of information at once (That doesn't seem to be a standard library command, so I can't tell you if that's an option for you).

If you know that `root.findall()` returns in the correct order then you should be able to use this:

```
pods = root.findall('.//pod')
plain_text = root.findall('.//plaintext')
for title,info in zip(pods,plain_text):
    joined += "{0} {1}\n\n".format(title,info)
```

The built-in `zip()` function takes two lists and creates a new list where the first element is a combination of the first elements of the input lists, the second is a combination of the second elements of the input lists, etc... You can read more about `zip()` [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)